# Find Windows 7 driver for Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express

Tags: windows-7, drivers

We have a desktop computer here which has Ubuntu installed. We want to install Windows 7 on an identical computer, but now have no network connection. Windows doesn't recognize the network card.

On the Ubuntu PC I executed the following command:

```
lspci | awk '/net/ {print $1}' | xargs -i% lspci -ks %
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

When I search for Windows drivers using `RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express` (or other combinations) I only get Linux results.

**Where can I find the Windows driver for this network card?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try here:

http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Otherwise, I would suggest you look up your motherboard model on the [Gigabyte support website](http://www.gigabyte.com/support-downloads/download-center.aspx) and download the ethernet driver from there.

Hope this helps..

Comment: To expand on this, the file that worked for me was **Win7 and Server 2008 R2 Auto Installation Program**. I copied it to Windows, unzipped, and ran `autoinst.exe`. Worked like a charm.

Comment: And then, of course, having gotten online with a seven-year-old unpatched version of Windows, it was 0wnz0red almost at once. Remember to download SP1 and the other updates ahead of time! [This article](https://www.howtogeek.com/255435/how-to-update-windows-7-all-at-once-with-microsofts-convenience-rollup/) seems useful in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

I found two versions of the driver :

- [RealTek RTL8111 Driver
  v.7.076](https://driverscollection.com/?file_cid=457427993557e8fb0bbf17976b1)
- [Realtek Gigabit Ethernet Driver 7.069 for Windows 7](http://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/17040/)

Answer (score 0):

Up-to-date link as of August 2019 :

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software